# Google Chrome Plugin: How to detect URL of selected tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to attempt my first Google Chrome Extension and have a question.  My end goal is to be able to select a button which will perform the following:

1. Grab the current URL of the selected tab (Ex: www.google.com)
2. Open a new tab using the URL from step 1 and appending a query string to the end (Ex: www.google.com?filter=0)

Currently, I was able to figure out how to open a create a new tab which loads a specified URL.  What I am unsure of how to detect the URL from the selected tab and load that value in the new tab.  Suggestions?  Thanks in advance!!

Code below:

[popup.html]

```
    <html>
<head>

<style>

body {
  min-width:175px;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

</style>


<script>

 function createTab() {
  chrome.tabs.create({'url': 'http://www.google.com'});
 }

 function show_alert()
 {
 alert("I am an alert box!");
 }

</script>
</head>

<body>

<input type="button" onclick="createTab()" value="Create New Tab" />
<hr/>
<input type="button" onclick="show_alert()" value="Show alert box" />

</body>
</html>
```

[manifest.json]

```
{
  "name": "IGX Plugin",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "IGX Plugin",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "favicon.ico",
 "popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]


}
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979583/how-can-i-get-the-url-for-a-google-chrome-tab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    alert(tab.url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`chrome.tabs.getSelected` [has been deprecated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getSelected). so we should use `tabs.query({active: true}...` instead:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, tabs => alert(tabs[0].url));
```