# Script doesn't open the right link

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My code:

```
var link;
var wid;
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
    link = tab.url;
});
http.open('get', 'http://surfkid.redio.de/linki.php?site_url='+link);
function insertReply() {

}
http.onreadystatechange = insertReply();
http.send(null);
```

This don't work, but I don't know why.

Comment: What doesn't work?  What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: What is it trying to do? What happens instead?

Comment: that php writes the url in a db. The php works perfekt but the extention not.

Comment: @nathon nothing happen, no entry in the db was made

Comment: -1. It's not PHP & OP doesn't explain what doesn't work.

Comment: Is that page actually called? Do you get error messages in the JavaScript console (Sh+Ct+J)?

Comment: I think you at least need to [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) your `link` variable.

Comment: the console says nothing

Comment: @marcel not better : <script type="text/javascript">
var link;
var wid;
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
    link = tab.url;
});
link = encodeURIComponent(link);
http.open('get', 'http://surfkid.redio.de/linki.php?site_url='+link);
function insertReply() {

}
http.onreadystatechange = insertReply();
http.send(null);

</script>

Comment: @marcel sorry my english is too bad for translating this:Get rid of those parentheses, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to initiate an instance of `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

You need to use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to properly encode your query parameter:

```
http.open('get', 'http://surfkid.redio.de/linki.php?site_url='+encodeURIComponent(link));
```

You want to attach an event listener to `http.onreadystatechange`, but you're actually calling `insertReply` and set its return value instead. Get rid of those parentheses:

```
http.onreadystatechange = insertReply;
```

**UPDATE:** `chrome.tabs.getSelected` works asynchronously, so when accessing `link` after the function is executed, it probably still is `undefined` (also see [How can I get the URL for a Google Chrome tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979583/how-can-i-get-the-url-for-a-google-chrome-tab)) Put your code in the callback handler. Complete script:

```
var wid,
    http = new XMLHttpRequest();

chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
    http.open('get', 'http://surfkid.redio.de/linki.php?site_url=' + encodeURIComponent(tab.url));
    http.onreadystatechange = insertReply;
    http.send(null);
});

function insertReply() {

}
```

Comment: now i have a db entry but the entry is: . undefined. my php code: <?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("xxx") or die(mysql_error());
$url= $_GET['site_url'];
$tmp = mysql_query("Insert into link (link) VALUES ('. $url. ')");
echo "OK"
?>​

Comment: @user: Please don't post code within comments, but update your question and eventually post a comment that you did so. This is hardly legible.

Comment: sorry php --> http://codeviewer.org/view/code:13cf link.html --> http://codeviewer.org/view/code:13ce mainifest --> http://codeviewer.org/view/code:13d0

Comment: ohhh you fixed something link.html -->http://codeviewer.org/view/code:13d1

Comment: so you are my hero ^^ it works

Comment: @user: You're welcome, nice to know it works, despite the not very clear description of your issue. Please don't use Pastebins (like codeviewer.org) to post snippets of code, but edit your question and paste your code in there, so we don't need to visit another site to view it (and mind the 4 spaces, which are inserted automatically after selecting your code and pressing the code button, the one with `010101`).