# Get URL of a specific tab?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In Google Chrome, how would I get the URL of the page being shown on a specific tab?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the URL for a Google Chrome tab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979583/how-can-i-get-the-url-for-a-google-chrome-tab)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This depends on how you define *specific tab*. There are numerous functions to get a tab, which in turn give you back a [Tab object](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#type-Tab). This object has a url attribute.

Let's take the current selected tab for example. You get a handle on it with [chrome.tabs.getSelected](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-getSelected). Where `null` is a WindowID, and defaults to the current window.

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) { 
    alert(tab.url);
})
```

For more information I suggest you have a look at the [documentation of the API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html).

Answer (score 7):

According to the Google Chrome Extensions documentation, you can retrieve a tab's url by calling the `chrome.tabs.get(integer tabId, function callback)` method to get a Tab object containing the following fields:

> id ( integer )
>   The ID of the tab. Tab IDs are unique within a browser session.
>
> index ( integer )
>   The zero-based index of the tab within its window.
>
> windowId ( integer )
>   The ID of the window the tab is contained within.
>
> selected ( boolean )
>   Whether the tab is selected.
>
> pinned ( boolean )
>   Whether the tab is pinned.
>
> **url ( string )**
>   **The URL the tab is displaying**
>
> title ( optional string )
>   The title of the tab. This may not be available if the tab is loading.
>
> favIconUrl ( optional string )
>   The URL of the tab's favicon. This may not be available if the tab is loading.
>
> status ( optional string )
>   Either loading or complete.
>
> incognito ( boolean )
>   Whether the tab is in an incognito window.

The `"tabs"` element also needs to be added to the permissions section of the manifest.

```
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
```