# Google Chrome Extension get page information

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a google chrome extension, and I need to get the current page URL and title. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It is already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922684/get-url-of-a-specific-tab

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979583/how-can-i-get-the-url-for-a-google-chrome-tab

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) { //<-- "tab" has all the information
    console.log(tab.url);       //returns the url
    console.log(tab.title);     //returns the title
});
```

For more please read [`chrome.tabs`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs). About the `tab` object, read [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab).

---

**Note:** `chrome.tabs.getSelected` [has been deprecated](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getSelected) [since Chrome 16](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/whats_new#16). As the documentation has suggested, [`chrome.tabs.query()`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) should be used along with the argument `{'active': true}` to select the active tab.

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
    tabs[0].url;     //url
    tabs[0].title;   //title
});
```

Comment: For anyone seeing this lately, it's worth pointing out that chrome.tabs.getSelected() has been deprecated, and Konstantin's answer is now the correct answer to this question.

Comment: Note that "currentWindow" doesn't refer to what you probably think it refers to. You most likely want to use "lastFocusedWindow", which is the window in focus, in conjunction with "active", which is the tab in focus.

Answer (score 7):

The method `getSelected()` has been deprecated since Google Chrome 16 (but many articles in the official documentation had not yet been updated). [Official message is here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/whats_new.html#16). To get the tab that is selected in the specified window, use `chrome.tabs.query()` with the argument `{'active': true}`. So now it should looks like this:

```
chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
  console.log(tabs[0].url);
  console.log(tabs[0].title);
});
```

**Edit**: `tabs[0]` is the first active tab.