# How to get Chrome status bar text

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension and I want to get Chrome status bar text in extension or content script.
But I cannot find any chrome.* API or javascript to achieve this.
So is there any way to get Chrome status bar text?

Comment: I'm afraid not, however it's almost always a `a` link right ... and the showed thing is `link.href` (note: this is NOT the href attr, this is the prop) so listen on hovering on document checking for `a`: `document.addEventListener('mouseover', e => (e.target.tagName === 'A') ? console.log(e.target.href) : null);`

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for the status that shows up when the cursor remains over a link, then you could use Javascript to listen for hover/mouseover events on any `a` and get the object's href attribute.

Alternatively, if you want the title you can get that code here [Google Chrome Extension get page information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871309/google-chrome-extension-get-page-information#answer-6876999)

[image: chrome status and title]