# How to develop a simple chrome extension that navigate to a website

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need to create a simple chrome extension which when clicked have to navigate to that website.I have been searching long.But I couldn't find out.Please help me.
Here is my manifest.json file

```
{
 "name": "My First Extension",
 "version": "1.0",
 "description": "The first extension that I made.",
    "manifest_version":2,
     "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon_128.png"
 },
 "background_page": "background.html",
 "permissions": [
  "tabs"
]
}
```

this is my background.html

```
   <script>
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
     chrome.tabs.create({'url': "http://calpinemate.com"});
   </script>
```

I am just trying to navigate into my site.But it is not working.Anyone please help me.I only have these two files in my directory and an image icon_128.png.Please help me

Comment: Did you try this link? You may be able to modify it to your needs. Or take the basic premises of it and try to implement it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183696/chrome-extension-open-tab-go-to-url-fill-form-and-submit-form

Comment: I wonder how the above link might help...

Comment: @user3016912: BTW, I updated my answer with a demonstration of how to change the extension icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

`background_page` is no longer supported in `manifest_version` 2. Instead use the [new format](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html). You can also remove the `tabs` permissions value since `chrome.tabs.create` doesn't require it.

```
{
    "name": "My First Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "The first extension that I made.",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon_128.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}
```

Move `background.html` to `background.js`, and remove the `<script></script>` tags.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({'url': "http://calpinemate.com"});
});
```

Comment: thank you abraham.I don't know much about adding extensions..Thank you so much for correcting me.

Comment: I need to clarify some more doubts.PLease help me.Now it have been navigated to my website.It is a login page.When the user logs on to it, the extension icon should appear green and when the user logs out,it should appear red.how can I do it?Please help me

Comment: Look at [sending messages from web pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#external-webpage)

Comment: should i use cookies or session ??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because you are missing theclosibg `})` in your background page.
Besides, you don't need any permissions for what you want and it is recommended to use anon-persistent background page (a.k.a. **[event page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html)**).

---

E.g.:

**background.js:**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({ "url": "http://calpinemate.com" });
});
```

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":        "Test Extension",
    "description": "...",
    "version":     "0.0",

    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Test Extension"
        "default_icon": "icon_128.png"
    }
}
```

---

BTW, since you seem to be interested in changing the extension icon, you can take a look into **[chrome.browserAction.setIcon()](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setIcon)**.
Below is an example that toggles the extension icon when the user clicks on the browser-action (you can adapt it according to your specific needs).

**background.js**:

```
var icons = ["red.png", "green.png"];

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    var iconIdx = localStorage.getItem("iconIdx");
    var newIdx = iconIdx ? (parseInt(iconIdx) + 1) % 2 : 1;
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: icons[newIdx] });
    localStorage.setItem("iconIdx", newIdx);
});
```