# I want to get the url from all tabs in Chrome and IE from C# windows form button click

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to get the URL from all open tabs. I have searched on Google but could not find any luck. I want to read and log the URL from all open tab from Chrome And IE.

I am using C# windows form application.

Thanks in Advance..
Umang

Comment: If there is no API you might stuggle!

Comment: Relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979583/how-can-i-get-the-url-for-a-google-chrome-tab

Answer (score 2):

I understand what you need to do but I would be surprised if IE and Chrome would expose the tabs and the urls in a simple and similar way to external applications, I think the way to go is to build a Chrome extension and an IE plugin or Addin to get those information while running within the browser scope, then you can send this info to an external application or to a web service etc... you will find a way to get the info out once you have got this url list inside your own code running with the browser.

see here for some starting point / ideas

Chrome extensions:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/index.html

IE development:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250436(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Hi Davide, 

Thanks for your reply.
Actually I did some Google and found something related to SendMessage function. But I could not get the URL from this. Though I downloaded a sample from the Net buts its in VB.Net, in that exapmle on click of a button you can get the active tab URL. but i want this all to be in the C#.

Thanks