# Google chrome extension get URL?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am trying to make a google extension for shortening URL when the user click the extension
an new tab will be opened. 
Just like this:

```
www.mysite.net/api.php?myurl
```

Where `myurl` is the current tab URL.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's nice. So what's your question?

Comment: i wanted to know which codes i will need

Comment: i have searched google developer section but it is too big and my idea is small thanks for response

Comment: Look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979583/how-can-i-get-the-url-for-a-google-chrome-tab