# Why doesn't chrome.tabs.query() return the tab's URL when called using RequireJS in a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, requirejs

I have a simple Chrome extension that adds a browser action.  When the extension's popup is opened, it needs to access the current tab's URL.  Since it doesn't need access to all the tabs, I just have the `activeTab` permission specified in the manifest:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "RequireJS Test",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "Test RequireJS and the activeTab permission.",
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "js/*",
        "html/*",
        "css/*",
        "img/*"
    ]
}
```

In theory, that should give the popup access to the active tab's URL, but the URL is not returned when I query the tabs from within a `require()` call in the popup's `main.js` file:

```
require([], function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({"active": true, "lastFocusedWindow": true}, function (tabs) {
        var url = tabs[0].url;
        console.log("URL from main.js", url);
    });

    console.log("URL from global var accessed in main.js", tabURL);
});
```

The console shows `undefined` for the URL.  However, if I make the same call from a plain .js file that doesn't use `require()`, it works fine:

```
chrome.tabs.query({"active": true, "lastFocusedWindow": true}, function (tabs) {
    tabURL = tabs[0].url;
    console.log("URL from get-url.js", tabURL);
});
```

That displays the correct URL, and I can access that global `tabURL` inside the `require()` call just fine.  When I right-click the browser button and inspect the popup, the console output looks like this:

```
URL from get-url.js http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
URL from global var accessed in main.js http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
URL from main.js undefined
```

Even stranger is that I've *sometimes* seen the URL available from within that call to `chrome.tabs.query()` inside the `require()` call.  But mostly it doesn't work.  Something about how RequireJS loads scripts seems to confuse Chrome and take away the URL access for the loaded script.  This is in Chrome 40 on Windows.

Obviously, the workaround is to grab the URL in a separate script and store it in a variable, but that feels a bit kludgy.  I'd like to see if there's a proper way of getting this to work with RequireJS.

The full plugin source is here if anyone wants to test it on their machine: https://github.com/fwextensions/requirejs-url-test

---

### Edit

As Rob W. explains below, this actually has nothing to do with RequireJS.  The only reason that the code in my `get-url.js` file above returned the correct URL was that it happened to run before the devtools window opened.  If I change that file to this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
chrome.tabs.query({"active": true, "lastFocusedWindow": true}, function (tabs) {
    tabURL = tabs[0].url;
    console.log("URL from get-url.js", tabURL);
});
}, 5000);
```

Then it runs after the devtools window is open and fails as well.  RequireJS isn't the culprit.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You don't see a URL because you've only set the `activeTab` permission (not the `tabs`) permission AND the last focused window is the developer tools (for which you don't have `activeTab` access) (and since Chrome 41, devtools tabs/windows [are invisible to extensions](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/4af3ec98321a5f2f942dfcb52f9e329f18bbd7d7), so `tabs` will be an empty array).

The good news is that this problem is specific to the devtools window being opened for your extension page, so the issue only occurs during development and not during actual use by users.

Extension popups are associated with a window, so you can use `chrome.tabs.query` with `currentWindow:true` to get the correct answer:

```js
chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
}, function(tabs) {
    var tabURL = tabs[0].url;
    console.log(tabURL);
});
```

Comment: I've filed a bug report: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=462939

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried replacing the `console.log()` calls with `alert()` and even with still querying for `lastFocusedWindow`, each alert showed the correct URL, which confirms that the issue was opening the devtools window by inspecting the popup. That also explains why I would occasionally see the correct URL in `main.js`: the code must have finished running just before devtools opened, so `lastFocusedWindow` was still the web page. RequireJS had nothing to do with it.

Comment: It was working before I optimized my code slightly, then I guess the speed difference mattered (since chrome. functions are asynchronous). Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can I get content of tab (html/body response) ? @RobW

Comment: It's not as simple as this, unfortunately. On Chromium/Linux 116 `currentWindow` normally gives a `url`, but sometimes doesn't. Very much looks like a bug.

Answer (score 11):

To overcome the devTools bug that Rob W. reported in his post, the following `getActiveTab` workaround seems to consistently work for me (even when there are multiple devTools windows open).  It works by always saving a reference to the `activeTabId` in the background page, whenever the `tabs.onActivated` event fires.

```
var activeTabId;

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {
  activeTabId = activeInfo.tabId;
});

function getActiveTab(callback) {
  chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
    var tab = tabs[0];

    if (tab) {
      callback(tab);
    } else {
      chrome.tabs.get(activeTabId, function (tab) {
        if (tab) {
          callback(tab);
        } else {
          console.log('No active tab identified.');
        }
      });

    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Bug, and workaround is (in "service_worker": "background.js"):

```
var activeTab; // Workaround for bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=462939

// On activated tabs (triggered immediately after declaration)
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(tab) {
    activeTab = tab;
    console.debug(activeTab);
});
```

Comment: This only gets `tabid` and `windowid`, not full properties (including `url` and `title`) as per needs of original question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Fixed it by adding permission for the host you want to access.

```
"host_permissions": [
  "https://www.blogger.com/",
  "https://*.google.com/"
],
```

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions