# Getting my head wrapped around Chrome app and extension messaging with specific setup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, serial-port

I'm trying to build a sample extension that can field incoming messages from a serial device connected to the computer and have that affect an on screen UI element.
[image]

For example.  Lets say the extension is a running tally of total images encountered while browsing pages.  The extension shows a little box in the top right that just keeps count of images encountered.  So with each tab I open or each page i navigate to, the extension box (not a pop up but appears as an overlay on every page) has a number that just keeps increasing.  The extension has a background.js script used to listen to external messages coming from the chrome serial app and then relays that information to the content script.

Then I have a serial device connected via usb to the computer.  I am using [this guy's chrome serial app](https://github.com/garrows/browser-serialport/tree/master/demo) to read in some serial numbers that are coming in.  I want these numbers to decrement the total in the extension UI image counter, for example.

I've read through the Chrome messaging api and thought I could figure out how to send these messages between the chrome app and the chrome extension.
Placed the following in Chrome Serial App's background js which received some info from the content script about incoming serial readings:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( 
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        sendResponse("Got something!");
        console.log(request);
        var comPort = chrome.runtime.connect(extId);
        comPort.postMessage(request);

})
```

Then, from my understanding, I need to have the background.js listen for messages broadcasted from the Chrome serial app then forward that along to the running content script (tabs.connect) using the following code:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnectExternal.addListener(function(port) {
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);

        //relay the decrement amount
        chrome.tabs.query({active:true, currentWindow:true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, msg, function(response) {
                console.log("sent" + msg );
            });
        });
    });
});
```

And finally, setup a listener in the content script to listen for the number coming through.

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    console.log(msg)
    // decrement the value in the ui box

    });
})
```

Besically.  Nothing is happening.  The code seems to check out but there is no communication from the serial chrome app to the extension.

Any insight would be appreciated.

EDIT: 
I have the serial side of things working well.  The serial app's background js is chatting with the content script.  Now I am just trying to pass things over to the extension which nothing seems to be coming through.

EDIT #2:
Working through it.  Slowly getting there. I seem to be held up in chrome.tabs.sendMessage...
It is throwing me "cannot read property 'id' of undefined".  though I swear I am writing this the right way.  ***Stupid me, by defining chrome.tabs.query query info with currentWindow:true and when during debug, keeping dev tools window active, I was preventing myself from getting the actual tab information.  Stupid mistake...learned that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28786723/why-doesnt-chrome-tabs-query-return-the-tabs-url-when-called-using-requirejs)!

Comment: `comPort.postMessage({serialReading});` is a syntax error. You should start by debugging your code - for example, from `chrome://inspect/#apps`

Comment: Thanks Xan.  Yeah I figured that out and posted the edits.  I seem to be stuck at chrome.tabs.sendMessage as it keeps giving me an error that tabs is undefined.

Comment: It's not `onConnect`, it's `onMessage` at the last stage. I guess I could post an answer, but your question morphed so much I don't know what exactly to answer and whether it'll be useful.

Comment: I realize it...it's just that i seem to make headway and the issues starting changing.  Apologies.  I see the last stage issue and am just trying to get there.   Any insight into the tabs.query error?

Comment: ahh I see....lots of info on asynchronous nature of js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as is probably obvious the issue with nothing working was a multi-front issue having to do primarily with usual issues an extension noob might encounter.   But for the sake of those in similar situations I figure I'd post working code from what I provided above. Basically used console to make sure I was getting the values all the way through.

**main.js** message passing section of Chrome Serial App included the following to send to background.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(value);
```

**background.js** message passing section of the Chrome Serial App (link to full app in original question) which received from above and sent messages cross extension

```
var extId = "xxxxx"   //actual ID extension
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( 
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        sendResponse("Got something!");
        console.log(request);//receives 
        var comPort = chrome.runtime.connect(extId);//connects to extension
        comPort.postMessage(request);//sends to extension

})
```

**background.js** message passing section of the extension receiving serial information from the chrome app and then sending to the content script.  Make sure that when you are debugging that you don't have the devtools window active or else it'll throw an error.

```
function sendToInject(value){
    chrome.tabs.query({active:true, currentWindow:true}, function(tabs) {

        if (tabs[0] != null)
            console.log(tabs[0].id);
        else {
            console.log("??");
        }
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, value, function(response) {
            console.log(value );
        });
    });
}
chrome.runtime.onConnectExternal.addListener(function(port) {
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
        sendToInject(msg);

    });
});
```

**inject.js** message passing section of the main extension content script to receive the value from serial all the way through to the webpage.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(value) {

//do something with the request
    console.log(value);

});
```