# url remains undefined in chrome.tabs.query

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get the current tab url in chrome extension as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14251218/4202092) answer. But the value of url remains always undefined. What could be the reason?

**EDIT**

Here is my code

```
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
    var url = tabs[0].url;
});
```

I have defined the tabs permission in my manifest file

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: @sid I have added the code. Please see

Comment: How do you know `url` is undefined?  Then we'll close it as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/2336725

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get `url` of current `tab` then there is no need for `lastFocusedWindow`.

I assume by current `tab` you mean current `tab` in current `window`.

More Info about current window : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#current-window

Use this code:

```
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'currentWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
    var url = tabs[0].url;
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but still the error remains as it is.

Comment: Same error for me. So far I observe this error happen only on non-secure pages (http, not https); is that a factor?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. This was an issue of variable scope. I have declared the variable as global outside the function, and then it worked.

```
var url;

chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
    url = tabs[0].url;
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to access the value of url outside the callback function?

Comment: This does not do anything at all. The `url` var local to the function has nothing to do with the `url` var in the global scope. You probably forgot to reload the extension after applying changes to manifest.json

Comment: I edited the answer :) Forgot to delete the `var` part

Answer (score 0):

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "bookmarks",
    "http://www.blogger.com/",
    "http://*.google.com/",
    "unlimitedStorage"
],
```

Add permissions in `manifest.json`.

Comment: There are lots of unnecessary permissions here. Only the `tabs` permission is needed

Comment: And the OP said `I have defined the tabs permission in my manifest file` So this is a low quality answer?