# Current URL from included javascript file in a google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My extension shows how many times I have visited specific websites(youtube.com, quora.com), save in local storage and show it when a new tab is opened.The structure of extension looks like:

- index.html
- manifest.json
- script.js

manifest.json

```
    {
      "manifest_version": 2,

      "name": "Getting started example",
      "description": "",
      "version": "1.0",
      "chrome_url_overrides" : {
        "newtab": "index.html"
      }
    }
```

index.html includes script.js.My question is how do I track the list of visited urls.Do I need to use the background page or can I use chrome API for current url in script.js?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the URL for a Google Chrome tab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979583/how-can-i-get-the-url-for-a-google-chrome-tab)

Comment: @Gothdo Can I use `chrome.tabs.query` in script.js or do I need to use it in a background page.