# How can I change my chrome extension popup based on the current website?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

For example,
If I’m on website x and I click my web extension I want popupX.html to appear. 
However, if I’m currently on website y and I click my extension I want popupY.html to appear. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1979583/1531971

Comment: See documentation for chrome.browserAction.setPopup