# URL Reading & Modifying Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I am trying to make a chrome extension. I need it to take a URL, and modify a few characters specific characters and send you to newly edited URL. How would I do So?

Comment: See answers for chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest to redirect a URL, and a [demo extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:onbeforerequest).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the URL of the current tab from a Google Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979583/how-can-i-get-the-url-of-the-current-tab-from-a-google-chrome-extension)

Answer (score 0):

You can use chrome.tabs.query too

```
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tab) {
      chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: your_new_url});
});
```