# How do I send a content script variable to a background script? (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I want to send a variable called "website_hostname" from the content-script to the background script. It contains the hostname of the current website you're on.

Content Script:

```
var website_hostname =  window.location.href;

//Code to send website_hostname
```

Background Script:

```
// Get website_hostname
```

Comment: There should be no need to send it because the background script can [read the URL directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979583/how-can-i-get-the-url-of-the-current-tab-from-a-google-chrome-extension).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do that by using chrome onMessage.

in content,

```
    //content-script.js
    
     function notifyExtension() {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"url": window.loaction.href});
    }
    //background.js
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(notify);

    function notify(message) {
         variable = message.url
      });
    }
```

I got this from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/onMessage

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what suggested to you in the previous answer
But to do this it will be better use long lived connections port

Long-lived connections https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect() Send a message to background page port.postMessage()
```

Listener

```
for response port.onMessage.addListener()
```